# postfix header_checks - regex spanning multiple lines

Tags: postfix, spam, regex, spam-filter, smtp-headers

I would like to create a spam filter that spans multiple lines in headers. This is my `/etc/postfix/header_checks` file:

```
/^From:.*name[0-9]+@.+[\r\n]+To:.*name@domain\.com/  REJECT
```

It's a valid regex, but doesn't work, because *header_checks* applies the filters to one line at a time. How can I check for multiple headers at the same time? Matching against the whole raw headers block would work just fine, but I can't find an option for that.

Comment: `but I can't find an option for that.` ---> Yes your desired option doesn't exist in Postfix. You need **external** content filter to achieve your goal.

Comment: @masegaloeh can you suggest some simple external filter that could do this?

Comment: You can start by visiting the [postfix addon page](http://www.postfix.org/addon.html)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe an option to this case is put a conditional in the header field:

```
/^(From|To):.*name[0-9]+@.*/  REJECT
```

Comment: That wouldn't work, as both the conditions need to be true at the same time